# The proper way to use でも

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I'm just wondering if I'm using the word でも correctly here.

> わたし は たいてい おちゃ を のみます。 でも ときどき おさけ を のみます。

From what I've read you don't usually use でも in the middle of a sentence and I've seen a lot of comparisons with a word called けど, but right now I'm just really concerned with whether or not this example I made is the correct way to use でも.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using でも correctly in this sentence.

And this sentence would be much better if you say "おさけ**も**" instead of "おさけを". ([も ≒ also](http://www.punipunijapan.com/grammar-lesson-6-particle-%E3%82%82-mo/))

Comment: 状況の読み間違いかもしれませんが、ここでは特に「も」にする必要はない（すると意味が変わる）ように思うのですが…。

Comment: @broccoliforest Yeah, the original choice works when the writer wants to express it as if referring to alcohol is out of readers' anticipation.